# How to prevent submitting similar data to my database using PHP?

Tags: php, sql, duplicates

How can to prevent submitting similar data to my database using PHP OR SQL(via PHP)?

EXAMPLE:

**First entry:**

> name1, idno1 (This data saves to my database)

**Second entry(with same data):**

> name1, idno1 (This should alert the user and abort the argument)

Comment: sadly you will have to either check the db or cache results that you want to validate before doing an insert

Comment: You can declare the fields as `unique` field in DB.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a unique index which prevents duplicates.

Comment: then there is nothing to do with the form in the PHP?